# bash variable getting some weird hex data from Command substitution calling a script containing a bc calculation

Tags: bash, bc

```
bash --version
GNU bash, version 5.1.16(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin21.1.0)
```

I'm calling a script (dewpoint) which contains a bc calculation that defines dewpoint based on temp(c) and humidity(%).  The response I receive (-17.1) looks good, but passing that into another bc script that converts it to temp(f) results in the following error.

```
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: ^[
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: ^[
(standard_in) 1: parse error
(standard_in) 1: parse error
```

The culprit seems??? to be the variable (dpC) assigned when calling dewpoint

```
dpC=$(dewpoint -5 38)
declare -p dpC
printf '%s' "$dpC" | hexdump -C
```

```
declare -- dpC="-17.1"
00000000  1b 28 42 1b 5b 6d 2d 31  37 2e 31                 |.(B.[m-17.1|
0000000b
```

I have no idea what or where the "1b 28 42 1b 5b 6d" is coming from.
I can clean it up with `dpC=${dpC//[^[:digit:].+-]/}`
but I don't want to do this after every call to dewpoint (I even tried adding this to dewpoint to no avail along with using echo and printf. I hope I made the issue clear.  Anyone have a clue what's going on?

dewpoint:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
bc -l <<< "define pa (n) {
         if (n >= 0.0) {
            return (7.5);
         } else {
            return (7.6);
         }
      }

      define pb (n) {
         if (n >= 0.0) {
            return (237.3);
         } else {
            return (240.7);
         }
      }

      define sdd (t) {
         return (6.1078 * e( l(10) * ((pa(t) * t) / (pb(t) + t)) ) );
      }

      define dd (r,t) {
         return (r / 100.0 * sdd(t));
      }

      /* factor 2.302585093 converts ln() to log() */
      v  = l(dd($2,$1) / 6.1078) / 2.302585093;
      tp = ((pb($1) * v) / (pa($1) - v));

      if ( tp >= 0.0 ) {
         tp = (tp + 0.05);
      } else {
         tp = (tp - 0.05);
      }

      scale = 1;
      (tp / 1.0);"
```

Comment: Maybe try `dpC="$(dewpoint -5 38)"` (note the quotes) and see if that works?

Comment: They look somewhat like terminal control bytes (1b5b6d is ESC-[m for example). What terminal program are you using?

Comment: Already tried the quotes, no quotes, echo and printf along with/out \n as well as command substitution inside dewpoint (with and without "dpC=${dpC//[^[:digit:].+-]/}").  Using iTerm on the Mac.  I've never come across this before.

Comment: Please show output of `echo $SHELL`

Comment: My Login default shell is /usr/local/bin/zsh .. but my scripts are all GNU Bash

Comment: bc --version
bc 1.06

Comment: Those are definitely Terminal escape sequences (they tell the terminal to use the default character display mode and G0 character set), but I don't see anything that should be inserting them. What does `dewpoint -5 38 | hexdump -C` show? What about putting `set -x` before the relevant part of the script, and seeing if that shows where they're getting added? Is it possible they're directly in the script itself (note that printing the script to the terminal won't show them, because the terminal will interpret and apply them rather than displaying them)?

Comment: are you running oh-my-zsh in your .zshrc? or oh-my-bash in your .bashrc? or anything else that outputs terminal escape codes whenever the shell is started?    programs like these achieve their garish eye-bleeds by inserting escape sequences wherever they possibly can.

Comment: Not running oh-my-zsh. what's weird is the value is fine inside dewpoint, but on exit the escape sequences are inserted. `dewpoint -5 38 | hexdump -C
00000000  1b 28 42 1b 5b 6d 2d 31  37 2e 31 0a              |.(B.[m-17.1.|
0000000c`
`
I modified dewpoint to assign the calculation to a variable and ran the hexdump inside dewpoint.

`dewpoint -5 38
00000000  2d 31 37 2e 31                                    |-17.1|
00000005`

Comment: I renamed my .inputrc and .zshrc and made no difference.  I tried with the Mac "terminal" emulator instead of iTerm and that also did not make a difference

Comment: I moved dewpoint into a function and that seems to have fixed the issue.  Still very perplexed.